# Typescript equality operator vs Array.includes checks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have prepared the demo ([reproduction link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyYcUA5hGAFxHHIA%20yARDMFBmAPohwC2EZnWJNmAGzice-QcMYsAJnEhcsMLgCN2YABZD685nAUKoEDBi5jQsg6OOnzl6yAgAmffVEJgYAJ6eIiycyrZeLABewAAOzADcBAC%20BASgkLCIKACCJmYW%20HQOec42APzUyJxQoOTyIACuYmIJxEVOVjZu5ZVg1SC1TA1NLT2h3VU1dY3NdD7%20472Tg9MjUdELfQPIQzPJqeDQ8EjIAPIA7q5QBcTAChUNfBrQI2wc3LwCFRP9IxJSHxAvosfnQlCo1JptDogZspsNCrknBUco4LEkUjB6iAEGBgDhkAgzKEAHIQM4nEBnaAAClIFCoFXQHBwAG1mHTKGBmABdACU1wJOE42zJABFlHBkABefCJZCSNBkXFwMQAHnOlwAfAk6MAYMhqXIOVRpVKZUZERYOq5mIwGEayJzTea2laXO5bQx7QZjWBnZEYp7vfRff7mCFIEGHfS-WbzXMAnR%20YQDAB6VPIHRYABu0GQ%20N9clcZ3FpAAdK6MNKBQYWb7uRV2eY-ZXbemSH5ouZCTE-QBrEBYM5ViAAD0QkCafhIOmUJEdJp00BQwCrOBQahYletgkM2-dHkMa09wVIkcMCcCyESIzlEDEGBQKfoxdLcDrC7A3OrAGVgeRqSbYVW15OJkHbOAQAUTNl3zVx831Vh2H%20GQT3ESR3lQwwwQgVR1C0KBdE8ZI9kxbFcXxQkIBJMkKSpKAAHVfB0ABJbExHqBQIAAYSXBA%201pT9GUwVl2U-Hlk1mIU-VfCVqzwOUFVQJVgBVdULmgbUUhufVDVrC1URKG0ABot0tIyPVM5hjysiNBCsy9uTLUAEA4riMEEmNeSTGtwIzLNcyuAtPyLMUJQrcz5LkYgPxjBsWEgYDzLbDNAFBqQB4P%20QM4dGnXxkAULBzBAAByftBzOGCzBnOc8tXHpgCaOCN31MzDJ3ND906NDj0MOy0MvZBSiG5BAD4NwAUXbkG86DvB8n1CksJVizlvxlP9NkAxKW2S0C-OQBico7LsMB7aI-V0KAhxHKALquJczFKab0QIMicTxXAqJo8lKWgJjdDY1zOJ4vi%201%20nQAAkyAUBAsC4hQABVO3MTzOWE5kQDZX0JIFaGQGFWTSHkxSq2UwjVLVDVNJ1HSDTkNlOpM1rih3DwrJs09QmYBzfACJyXLcpHfW84hJLTfyczzYKY3mt8IsMqKDBi0MFQMpn3Q68zme6wNerPXdvG5nlG02%20Vkt2zgGrEGdQD7KtarXeDNxVS2mWwdGxJjHlJtvZB70fXz8ffJWqyQt5pAENC-kw8PsNCPDIUIvQVuQNaag25sTcM5hQMexIgA))

Here is my question:

```
interface Person {
  target:
    | "first_name"
    | "last_name"
    | "date_of_birth"
    | "address_line"
    | "address_line2"
    | "city"
    | "state"
    | "zip";
}

interface Address {
  address_line?: string | null;
  address_line2?: string | null;
  state?: string | null;
  city?: string | null;
  zip?: string | null;
}

interface Owner {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  date_of_birth: string | null;
  address: Address
}

function createNewOnwer(target: Person["target"]) {
  const newData = {} as Partial<Owner>;

  if (
    target === "address_line" ||
    target === "address_line2" ||
    target === "zip" ||
    target === "state" ||
    target === "city"
  ) {
    // hover on target
    newData.address = {
      [target]: "test address" // typescript knows exactelly that target here is one of "address_line" | "address_line2" | "zip" | "state" | "city"
    };
  } else {
    newData[target] = String("test address"); // and here one of "first_name" | "last_name" | "date_of_birth"
  }
}

function createNewOnwerWithIncludeCheck(target: Person["target"]) {
  const newData = {} as Partial<Owner>;

  if (
    ["address_line", "address_line2", "zip", "state", "city"].includes(target)
  ) {
    // hover on target
    newData.address = {
      [target]: "test address" // ⬅️ why it doesn't know here that it is still one of  "address_line" | "address_line2" | "zip" | "state" | "city" ??? 
    };
  } else {
    newData[target] = String("test address"); // Why typescript throws error here?
  }
}

function createNewOnwerWithIncludeCheckWithHardcodedTypes(target: Person["target"]) {
  const newData = {} as Partial<Owner>;

  if (
    ["address_line", "address_line2", "zip", "state", "city"].includes(target)
  ) {
    // hover on target
    newData.address = {
      [target as "address_line" | "address_line2" | "zip" | "state" | "city"]: "test address" // still thinks it is one of all Person["target"]
    };
  } else {
    newData[target as "first_name" | "last_name" | "date_of_birth"] = String("test address");
  }
}
```

1. How come when I use `===` checks against strings in the `if`, typescript is able to distinguish the types, and knows exactly what variants take under consideration? But when I use `Array.includes` as a check in the `if` it doesn't?
2. How can I make it work with `Array.includes` check in the `if`?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275, please see the following issue for a detailed explanation of why this is the case

Comment: The answer to 1 is that [equality checks act as type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) but `Array.includes()` does not, and the authoritative reason for that is described in [ms/TS#36275](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275). For 2, You could write your own type guard function that behaves the way you want, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5z72m), or even merge that into your own local type definitions for `Array.includes()` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND2QzW).

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining fully; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz it does thank you. Go a head, post an answer I will be happy to accept it ;)

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the series of [equality checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) like `target === "address_line"` works for you is because equality checks are one of the constructs that TypeScript uses to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the types of the expressions being checked.  That is, `x === y` can act as a *type guard* on `x` and `y`.

In general it is *possible* for function calls or method calls to act as type guards, but to do so they need to be annotated so their return type is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of the form `arg is Type` where `arg` is the name of a function parameter (or `this`), and where `Type` is some type narrower than `typeof arg`.  But [the standard TypeScript library typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/64d0d5ae140b7b26a09e75114517b418d6bcaa9f/lib/lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts#L27) for [the `Array.prototype.includes()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is not annotated this way.  It's not a type guard function.

Why not? It has been suggested, at [microsoft/TypeScript#36275](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275), but this suggestion was declined [because](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275#issuecomment-702233949) it would be too complicated to do so correctly.  Quite often, people call `array.includes(value)` without trying to narrow the type of `value`.  And if they *do* want that, they wouldn't necessarily be happy with the inverse, where `!array.includes(value)` implies that `value` is *not* the type of an array element.  If you have an array of strings like `["a", "b", "c"]`, the fact that `"z"` isn't in the array doesn't mean that *`"z"` isn't a `string`* (!).  So care would need to be taken to implement a type guard that doesn't have very strange effects.

---

Your options here are:

You could write your own standalone type guard function which calls `Array.prototype.includes()` inside of it, but doesn't try to affect how the compiler sees `Array.prototype.includes()` in general.  That's the safest thing to do, because you can control when your type guard function gets called:

```
function includes<T extends string>(arr: readonly T[], val: string): val is T {
  return (arr as readonly string[]).includes(val);
}

function createNewOnwerWithIncludeCheck(target: Person["target"]) {
  const newData: Partial<Owner> = {};
  if (includes(["address_line", "address_line2", "zip", "state", "city"], target)) {
    newData.address = { [target]: "test address" };
  } else {
    newData[target] = String("test address"); // okay
  }
}
```

So `includes()` is a standalone function which accepts an array of strings `arr` and a target string `val`, and returns `val is T`, where `T` is intended to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) inferred from the contents of `arr`.

You can see that it works as desired.

---

Or, you could decide to define a call signature for `Array.prototype.includes()` that makes it act as a type guard, and [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) it into your code base:

```
// declare global { // uncomment this if your code is in a module
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  includes<U extends (string extends U ? never : string)>(
    this: ReadonlyArray<U>, val: string): val is U;
}
interface Array<T> {
  includes<U extends (string extends U ? never : string)>(
    this: Array<U>, val: string): val is U;
}
// }
```

That will make it so that any time you call `array.includes(value)` where `array` whose elements are a subtype `U` of `string` (but crucially not `string` itself), and where `value` is a `string`, then a `true` result means that `value` is of type `U`, and a `false` result means that `value` is *not* of type `U`.  This is fairly complicated (which is why they didn't do it in microsoft/TypeScript#36275) and possibly fragile, so you might need to make sure it doesn't causes problems for your code base elsewhere.

Anyway, this will make your code work *more or less* as-is:

```
function createNewOnwerWithIncludeCheck2(target: Person["target"]) {
  const newData: Partial<Owner> = {};
  if ((["address_line", "address_line2", "zip", "state", "city"] as const).includes(target)) {
    newData.address = { [target]: "test address" };
  } else {
    newData[target] = String("test address"); // okay
  }
}
```

Except that the array literal needs that [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (`["a", "b", "c"] as const`) in order for the compiler to realize that the type of that array should be narrower than just `string[]`.  A `string[]` array wouldn't be helpful with narrowing.

Merging that in is the closest you can probably get to your desired state where your original code "just works", but I'd stay away from it and prefer the standalone type guard function.  There's little chance someone will call `includes(arr, val)` in some other part of your code, whereas `Array.prototype.includes()` is much more likely to be employed elsewhere.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACACnAzge3GgN7BpqSKwDm0kAXCWgD5oBE8os2kA+uIgLbQWDZiwA2iLrwFCRrACaIY3XPG4AjDpAAWw0qMTz5saNmzcxEWftaHjp85fDQATHqatkoSAE93oriVrDxYAL1AABxYAbmAAXxAIGAQUdABBIxMzIgY7LMcrAH5aNC5YCEoPcABXMTFY0jyHCysXYtLIcvBK5hq6ho6g9rKKqtr6hi9fYc7R3vGB8IiZrp60PomEsCg4JFQ0AHkAd2dYHNJQeRKa-nU4AfZOHj5BEpHugYkpF+g32Y+GIplKoNFptH9VmN+rlMg4Shl7GZ4iBgAB6VFoZDVLi4fhkHwRdCUaoUeRoeDVcDISCgfDAClUmn4NAQZBiaryUwAHgAKmhoAAPGDgeTYDqrAB8AAoKLASiZDPgxD40DyANoAXQANGgAG6IMQQioAShK+rELLFfOIpBMkGqsAIMtgZ0kaAV8iVKvelE1xoAdKz2ZzsFLzcbYlsGdTaQRkAqYAA5aBHA7gI5wADq3m0AEkqcHoABhbTQZAAayl5CoNBKWE4+DVLGr1EgLA1xvOmPwXHWKYAIkpEHWKDSDVzjqcJWgALxEOIDUDwNBSoMc0xSptNMwtZwsHUsbcFZxuA9LfesQIwC8sKZ+bVkCit42dm2kPtHQfkf1H2dENBqi2NAaiUzamJAaBHiwaALgwcT8mI2DoG+pDOJ+Q6AU+wF-gAyv8lBSmBvZQRGaDomguDlogPhwciaKooKES4LAEHID2EH8LgZJzgADLE5GCDWLLgPRaCcmyFBEmIuDqAaORJLsqRoAAStAirgMqaQutRvLTm+a4hlyACq-JCtAIpilKPqmcKopoCZhR9rqcBoEa3TGtKDCkDooDYCUqnqZp2k+MZEo6uabmUKaepyb59mRtsyR7OkwW6V2BnciZgq2ZZ1nZeZdkOU5LmRR5UpeWQ2i+fCqVGWFMWGuKJpmrFYpGQl5FRpSMbMvGalJimaYZrA2Y6PmbLriWZbli4VZYXQmA4I2zbze2r6TOxH5fsOmCjqA46TnA05zoQsEXMuUqboesI7k4QgHkeu6uDe54Hle92eN496QWKbHgFwAYZaGQGQC+XaoQOQ4-jdYonQBIMgawMDETD0FnTBCFIeDW0YQjuH4YRyMQSR0RkRilHUbRyJAA)

Comment: I am impressed of your knowledge. Would you care to help me understand another issue? Thank you very much, regardless of the answer :)